# How to convert a m4a sound file to mp3?

Tags: mp3, convert, m4a

I tried to convert an `.m4a` file to an `.mp3` file using `ffmpeg` with the following command:

```
$ ffmpeg -i music.m4a music.mp3
```

Unfortunately, I got a zero byte-sized file returned as output. The output of the command is as follows:

```
FFmpeg version 0.6-4:0.6-2ubuntu6.2, Copyright (c) 2000-2010 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Sep 16 2011 17:11:24 with gcc 4.4.5
  configuration: --extra-version=4:0.6-2ubuntu6.2 --prefix=/usr --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-vdpau --enable-bzlib --enable-libgsm --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-vaapi --enable-pthreads --enable-zlib --enable-libvpx --disable-stripping --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-shared --disable-static
  WARNING: library configuration mismatch
  libavutil   configuration: --extra-version=4:0.6-2ubuntu6.2 --prefix=/usr --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-vdpau --enable-bzlib --enable-libgsm --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-vaapi --enable-pthreads --enable-zlib --enable-libvpx --disable-stripping --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --shlibdir=/usr/lib/i686/cmov --cpu=i686 --enable-shared --disable-static --disable-ffmpeg --disable-ffplay
  libavcodec  configuration: --extra-version=4:0.6-2ubuntu6.2 --prefix=/usr --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-vdpau --enable-bzlib --enable-libgsm --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-vaapi --enable-pthreads --enable-zlib --enable-libvpx --disable-stripping --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --shlibdir=/usr/lib/i686/cmov --cpu=i686 --enable-shared --disable-static --disable-ffmpeg --disable-ffplay
  libavformat configuration: --extra-version=4:0.6-2ubuntu6.2 --prefix=/usr --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-vdpau --enable-bzlib --enable-libgsm --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-vaapi --enable-pthreads --enable-zlib --enable-libvpx --disable-stripping --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --shlibdir=/usr/lib/i686/cmov --cpu=i686 --enable-shared --disable-static --disable-ffmpeg --disable-ffplay
  libavdevice configuration: --extra-version=4:0.6-2ubuntu6.2 --prefix=/usr --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-vdpau --enable-bzlib --enable-libgsm --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-vaapi --enable-pthreads --enable-zlib --enable-libvpx --disable-stripping --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --shlibdir=/usr/lib/i686/cmov --cpu=i686 --enable-shared --disable-static --disable-ffmpeg --disable-ffplay
  libavfilter configuration: --extra-version=4:0.6-2ubuntu6.2 --prefix=/usr --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-vdpau --enable-bzlib --enable-libgsm --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-vaapi --enable-pthreads --enable-zlib --enable-libvpx --disable-stripping --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --shlibdir=/usr/lib/i686/cmov --cpu=i686 --enable-shared --disable-static --disable-ffmpeg --disable-ffplay
  libswscale  configuration: --extra-version=4:0.6-2ubuntu6.2 --prefix=/usr --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-vdpau --enable-bzlib --enable-libgsm --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-vaapi --enable-pthreads --enable-zlib --enable-libvpx --disable-stripping --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --shlibdir=/usr/lib/i686/cmov --cpu=i686 --enable-shared --disable-static --disable-ffmpeg --disable-ffplay
  libpostproc configuration: --extra-version=4:0.6-2ubuntu6.2 --prefix=/usr --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-vdpau --enable-bzlib --enable-libgsm --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-vaapi --enable-pthreads --enable-zlib --enable-libvpx --disable-stripping --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --shlibdir=/usr/lib/i686/cmov --cpu=i686 --enable-shared --disable-static --disable-ffmpeg --disable-ffplay
  libavutil     50.15. 1 / 50.15. 1
  libavcodec    52.72. 2 / 52.72. 2
  libavformat   52.64. 2 / 52.64. 2
  libavdevice   52. 2. 0 / 52. 2. 0
  libavfilter    1.19. 0 /  1.19. 0
  libswscale     0.11. 0 /  0.11. 0
  libpostproc   51. 2. 0 / 51. 2. 0
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'music.m4a':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : M4A 
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: M4A mp42isom
  Duration: 00:00:03.41, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 66 kb/s
    Stream #0.0(und): Audio: aac, 44100 Hz, mono, s16, 63 kb/s
Output #0, mp3, to 'music.mp3':
    Stream #0.0(und): Audio: 0x0000, 44100 Hz, mono, s16, 64 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0.0 -> #0.0
Encoder (codec id 86017) not found for output stream #0.0
```

How can I convert an `.m4a` sound file to an `.mp3` file format?

Comment: Install avconv and use this script: https://gist.github.com/bradenbest/cfba10c9df4b4c0daaab. You can also configure the `fformat` and `tformat` vars to change what audio formats you're converting between.

Comment: Your question was my answer :-D

Comment: Note that the asker's question runs out of the box as expected on Ubuntu 20.04, as answered by https://askubuntu.com/users/165216/eamonn-kenny below.

Answer (score 76):

The simple way to do it is:

```
ffmpeg -v 5 -y -i input.m4a -acodec libmp3lame -ac 2 -ab 192k output.mp3
```

If you want a script to wrap that, try [aac2mp3](https://web.archive.org/web/20110824051131/http://gimpel.gi.funpic.de/wiki/index.php?title=Howto%3aconvert_aac/mp4_to_wav/mp3/ogg_on_Linux#aac2mp3_script), which should work for you. (The syntax for that last statement was pulled from there.) Inline code included below:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# $Id: aac2mp3,v 1.2  03/30/2008 10:00 Daniel Tavares (dantavares@gmail.com) - 
# Based on Script -  rali Exp $
#
#
# Convert one or more AAC/M4A files to MP3.  Based on a script example
# I found at: http://gimpel.gi.funpic.de/Howtos/convert_aac/index.html
#
ME=`basename ${0}`
FFMPEG="/usr/bin/ffmpeg"
EXT="mp4"
BITRATE="128"
do_usage() {            # explanatory text
 echo "usage: ${ME} [-b nnn] [-e ext] [-f] [-c] [-r] [-v] [-h] [file list]"
 echo "       Convert music from AAC format to MP3"
 echo "  -m /path/app  Specify the location of ffmpeg(1)"
 echo "  -b nnn        bitrate for mp3 encoder to use"
 echo "  -e ext        Use .ext rather than .m4a extension"
 echo "  -f            Force overwrite of existing file"
 echo "  -c            Delete original AAC|M4A file(s)"
 echo "  -v            Verbose output"
 echo "  -h            This information"
 echo ""
 echo "For recursive directory, use: find -name '*.${EXT}' -exec ${ME} "{}" [args]     \;"
 exit 0
 }
do_error() {
 echo "$*"
 exit 1
 }
file_overwrite_check() {
 if [ "$FORCE" != "yes" ]
 then
   test -f "${1}" && do_error "${1} already exists."
 else
   test -f "${1}" && echo "  ${1} is being overwritten."
 fi
 }
create_mp3() {  # use ffmpeg(1) to convert from AAC to MP3
 file_overwrite_check "${2}"
 test $VERBOSE && echo -n "Converting file: ${1}"
 ${FFMPEG} -v 5 -y -i "${1}" -acodec libmp3lame -ac 2 -ab ${BITRATE}k "${2}";
 if [ $? -ne 0 ]
 then
   echo ""
   echo "Error!"
   do_cleanup
   do_error "Exiting"
 fi
 test $VERBOSE && echo ".  OK"
 }
do_cleanup() {  # Delete intermediate and (optionally) original file(s)
 test ${RMM4A} && rm -f "${1}"
 test $VERBOSE && echo ".  OK"
 }
do_set_bitrate() {
 test $VERBOSE && echo -n "Setting bitrate to: $1 kbps"
 BITRATE=$1
 test $VERBOSE && echo ".  OK"
 }
GETOPT=`getopt -o l:m:b:e:cfhrv -n ${ME} -- "$@"`
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
 do_usage
fi
eval set -- "$GETOPT"
while true
do
 case "$1" in
   -m) FFMPEG=$2 ; shift ; shift ;;
   -b) do_set_bitrate $2 ; shift ; shift ;;
   -e) EXT=$2 ; shift ; shift ;;
   -f) FORCE="yes" ; shift ;;
   -c) RMM4A="yes" ; shift ;;
   -v) VERBOSE="yes" ; shift ;;
   -h) do_usage ;;
   --) shift ; break ;;
    *)  do_usage ;;
 esac
done
test -f $FFMPEG || do_error "$FFMPEG not found. Use \"-m\" switch."
if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then                    # Convert all files in current directory
 for IFILE in *.${EXT}
 do
   if [ "${IFILE}" == "*.${EXT}" ]
   then
     do_error "Not found ${EXT} in this folder."
   fi
   OUT=`echo "${IFILE}" | sed -e "s/\.${EXT}//g"`
   create_mp3 "${IFILE}" "${OUT}.mp3"
   do_cleanup "${IFILE}" 
 done
else                    # Convert listed files
 for IFILE in "$*"
 do
   test -f "${IFILE}" || do_error "${IFILE} not found."  
   OUT=`echo "${IFILE}" | sed -e "s/\.${EXT}//g"`    
   create_mp3 "${IFILE}" "${OUT}.mp3"
   do_cleanup "${IFILE}"    
 done    
fi   
exit 0
```

Comment: Got (after many lines of text): `Unknown encoder 'libmp3lame' Error! Exiting`. With apt-get I can see `libmp3lame0` and `libmp3lame-dev`. I tried to install libmp3lame0, but nothing changed.

Comment: `ffmpeg` has been replaced by `avconv` in newer Ubuntu/Debian releases. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/432542/is-ffmpeg-missing-from-the-official-repositories-in-14-04 and install `libav-tools`

Comment: This does not work because ffmpeg is not in the Ubuntu repos...and nor are avconv or libav-tools. Could whoever is in charge of audio software please stop footling around and settle on something stable?

Comment: 'EXT="mp4"' needs to be changed to 'EXT="m4a"' according to the question. I would add the following explanatory text to make the understanding simpler: '# EXAMPLE: Will convert all files in the current directory with extension 
#   "m4a" to "mp3"
# bash SCRIPT_NAME -b 256 -v'

Comment: As of 15.04, ffmpeg is back in the repos: http://www.webupd8.org/2014/11/ffmpeg-returns-to-official-ubuntu.html As of 18.04, libav-tools and avconv are no longer available.

Comment: Upvote. It worked as-is. Nice script there as well (:-).

Comment: use `sudo apt install ffmpeg` to install

Answer (score 53):

This worked for me on Ubuntu 14.04:

```
avconv -i input.m4a ouptut.mp3
```

To obtain the `avconv` command, install [libav-tools](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/libav-tools) [image: Install libav-tools]:

```
sudo apt-get install libav-tools
```

Comment: FFMPEG is not deprecated. AvConv was a fork that decided to put that message in when somebody called it by the FFMPEG executable name

Comment: FYI. As of 18.04, libav-tools and avconv are no longer included in repos.

Comment: Just using `ffmpeg` directly, as specified in the question, works fine for me with ffmpeg 4.1.3 on macOS 10.14.4.

Answer (score 45):

[SoundConverter](http://soundconverter.org/) can do this without having to mess around on the command-line, and it's available in the Ubuntu Software Center:

[image: Install via the software center]

[image: soundcoverter main window and prefs]

[image: conversion inprogress]

Comment: If you have your files tagged by MusicBrainz, then find another solution:  https://bugs.launchpad.net/soundconverter/+bug/1174949

Comment: Christ on a crutch, what a mess. Soundconverter failed because Python was missing some packages, then it popped up an installer window for over 20 more packages, none of which it could install, of course, because it wasn't running as root, of course. Someone needs to rewrite the installer and the dependencies.

Comment: Program does not load Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: there is currently a bug in soundconverter related to m4a: https://bugs.launchpad.net/soundconverter/+bug/1512007

Comment: I am trying to avoid messing around with the gui: I want to automate it.

Answer (score 20):

I needed an alternate solution because 
- my files were sitting in recursive subdirectories
- I had spaces in paths.

So I eventually settled for :

```
 find . -type f -name '*.m4a' -exec bash -c 'avconv -i "$0" "${0/%m4a/mp3}"' '{}' \;
```

Then deleted the original files :

```
find . -type f -name '*.m4a' -exec bash -c 'rm "$0"' '{}' \;
```

Comment: For me, this is the top answer.  A small point - the deletion can be expressed more succinctly as: `find . -type f -name '*.m4a' -delete`

Comment: I modified the command by adding -y and -b:a 256k to make sure the program does not halt to ask for permission to overwrite existing mp3-files, and for a better quality (although I did not recognise a difference between the standard output of 128kbit/s (which was only half the bitrate my original m4a's had been):  find . -type f -name '*.m4a' -exec bash -c 'avconv -i "$0" -y -b:a 256k "${0/%m4a/mp3}"' '{}' \;

Comment: This command can be used successfully by substituting 'ffmpeg' for 'avconv'.

Answer (score 13):

In Ubuntu 20.04 the original command works out of the box:

```sh
ffmpeg -i music.m4a music.mp3
```

Comment: This is the best answer for anyone running ffmpeg on Ubuntu 20.04 (and maybe newer)

Comment: This worked for me with `ffmpeg version 4.1.6-1~deb10u1` on Debian 10 (buster)

Answer (score 9):

I created a script to do this.

My requirements were:

- Must maintain as many tags as possible
- Must retain album artwork if exists
- Must be 320K mp3s

Works on all m4a files in a directory, and outputs the new shiny Mp3s into a folder the script creates called Mp3. Warning; this script overwrites existing Mp3s in the output folder if they have the same name. Also uses files 'metadata.txt' and 'metadata2.txt' as temp files.

You'll need to install avconv if it doesn't exist already.

I couldn't figure out how to persist the 'Year' tag into ID3v1 tags, so I didn't enable that option.

```
#!/bin/bash
files=*.m4a
#create output folder if it doesnt exist
if [ ! -d Mp3 ]; then
        mkdir Mp3
fi

for file in $files; do
        mp3File=${file/%m4a/mp3}
        avconv -y -i "${file}" -f ffmetadata metadata.txt
        sed -e 's/^date=\(.*\)$/TYER=\1/' -e 's/^major_brand=.*$//' -e 's/^minor_version=.*$//' -e 's/^creation.*$//' -e 's/^compatible.*$//' -e 's/^encoder=.*$//' <metadata.txt >metadata2.txt
        avconv -y -i "${file}" -i metadata2.txt -ab 320k -map_metadata 1 -id3v2_version 3 "Mp3/${mp3File}"
done
```

Save it as 'convert.b', and then run the script by typing:

```
% bash convert.b
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: killer script, change the `avconv` to `ffmpeg` and that did the job. Please update the answer to include explanation for the various commands!

Answer (score 7):

Sometimes avconv and ffmpeg don't work so cleanly, so:

```
sudo apt-get install faad lame
faad myfile.m4a -w | lame - myfile.mp3
```

always works for me.

Comment: Oh thank you thank you...

Comment: I liked this one because I could easily parametrize `lame`. Somehow ffmpeg parametrization was a nightmare. For lame I just give `-V 0` or `-V 3` or something like that.

Answer (score 7):

Old question, but I don't see a very simple solution: Use **VLC**

In VLC you can load a **.m4a** file and convert it to **.MP3** very easyllie.

1. Open VLC (no need to load any file)
2. Click on **Media** or press **CTRL+R**
3. Click on **Conver/Save**
4. On **Profile** select **MP3**
5. Select destination
6. Click on **Start** and wait. To know if it doing something or not,
   look at the time bar.

I hope this will be usefull for somebody.

Comment: Very convenient! The only drawback I see is that this method seems to lose the metadata in the files, but I might have missed to check a box somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need the unrestricted libav packages in medibuntu repository.  Personally I would compile the latest ffmpeg with all codecs, as easy as 123
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=786095

Comment: If you don't want to compile ffmpeg: sudo apt-get install libavcodec-extra-53

Answer (score 1):

On my L-Ubuntu, `libav-tools` was not available. I installed `winff` :

`sudo apt-get install winff`

which provides a graphical tool to convert audio and video files from and into many different formats.

Just tried : it works fine for `.m4a` to `.mp3` :-)

Otherwise `vlc` also does a great job playing `.m4a` files :

`sudo apt-get install vlc`

Answer (score 0):

### Nautilus Script

This **Nautilus Script** allows user to convert selected file(s) like **m4a** files --skipping any mp3 or non-audio files-- to **mp3** format in the same location using **ffmpeg**. The new mp3 files will have the **highest variable bitrate** and preserve **most tags, except the year**.

```
#!/bin/sh
#Nautilus Script to convert selected file(s) - excluding any non-audio and MP3 file(s) - to MP3 format at highest quality with VBR (Variable Bit Rate)
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS="
"
for filename in $@; do
filetype="$(file -bi "$filename" | awk -F "; " '{print $1}' | awk -F "/" '{print $1}')"
if [ "$filetype" != audio ]; then
echo "Skip non-audio file"
else
filesubtype="$(file -bi "$filename" | awk -F "; " '{print $1}' | awk -F "/" '{print $2}')"
if [ "$filesubtype" != mpeg ]; then
file_name_in=$(basename "$filename")
file_name_out="$(basename "$filename" | sed 's/\.[^.]*$//').mp3"
ffmpeg -loglevel quiet -y -i "$file_name_in" -acodec libmp3lame -aq 0 "$file_name_out"
fi
fi
done
IFS=$OLDIFS
/usr/bin/canberra-gtk-play --id="dialog-information" &
notify-send "Selected file(s) converted to MP3 format, excluding any non-audio and MP3 file(s)" -i gtk-dialog-info -t 5 -u normal
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is a bit old, but I think people still see this question (like me), so I share what I have found that worked for me and has a nice UI: fre:ac (https://www.freac.org/). To use in ubuntu just download the binary for ubuntu, decompress and run the file calle `freac`, that's it. Enjoy!