# Is FFmpeg missing from the official repositories in 14.04?

Tags: software-installation, ffmpeg

I tried to install ffmpeg in trusty/Ubuntu 14.04 and got the following message:

```
$sudo apt-get install ffmpeg

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package ffmpeg is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'ffmpeg' has no installation candidate
```

Why isn't the package available?

Comment: What is the output of: apt-cache search ffmpeg | grep "ffmpeg" If you don't see `ffmpeg` in the list of returned results, then something has gone wrong with your repo manager. For now, I'd suggest installing by building from source. Download from [here.](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html)

Comment: Note that as of 2018, avconv is not in ffmpeg, and libav-tools is not in the Ubuntu repository!

Answer (score 263, accepted):

## Latest news

- WEB UPD8: **FFmpeg Returns** To The Official Ubuntu Repositories With [Ubuntu 15.04 Vivid Vervet](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/11/ffmpeg-returns-to-official-ubuntu.html)

---

## FFmpeg and libav

### libav from the Ubuntu repositories

Ubuntu started shipping the [libav](http://libav.org/) fork instead of [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) in [recent releases](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/technical-board/2011-June/000911.html). If you installed the [ffmpeg package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/ffmpeg), then you actually installed the [libav-tools package](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/libav-tools/) and a program that told you to use `avconv` instead of `ffmpeg` in the future, giving the impression that ffmpeg is deprecated, which it is not.

The transitional `ffmpeg` package seems to have been removed from trusty/Ubuntu 14.04 (compare the *package files* listing for saucy and trusty of [the source package](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libav)).

So one option is to install the libav-tools package and use `avconv` instead (NB that this is not "mainline" FFmpeg but a prominent fork instead).

### FFmpeg from a PPA on Launchpad

Another option is to use a PPA that provides FFmpeg.  Please have a look at the [FFmpeg download](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html) page for details of available PPAs and packages. You should check individual PPAs every once in a while if they are still up to date.

**Related questions:**

- [Are PPA's safe to add to my system and what are some "red flags" to watch out for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out-fo)

### Install from source

Another option is to install FFmpeg dependency packages, then manually compile+install it from source.

### Use static builds

While it may look a bit awkward from the packaging perspective, you could also use any static build from *trusted* sources. In my case I keep FFmpeg Windows 32-Bit and 64-Bit binaries along with x264-10-Bit binaries in a folder to run them in Wine or Windows whenever I need to.

---

> The following is what I could find, when researching this topic. I haven't been following the development of both projects closely and it is not my intention to blame anyone. You as a reader shouldn't do either.

## How did the fork happen?

Wikipedia states that the forked project as well as the initial release were announced on  March 13th 2011, however there is a bit more that was going on.

### Digging through Git commits

- **18 Jan 2011** - commit [f4f5cab94e0881cd30965b28f3d78d9c63d6918e](http://git.libav.org/?p=libav.git;a=commit;h=f4f5cab94e0881cd30965b28f3d78d9c63d6918e)

  The FFmpeg project leader Michael Niedermayer is removed from the `MAINTAINERS` file.
- **27 Jul 2011** - commit [6291d7e41605c0b1e9debfae8a2b1d4cf7b0e0b3](http://git.libav.org/?p=libav.git;a=commit;h=6291d7e41605c0b1e9debfae8a2b1d4cf7b0e0b3)

  `avconv` is introduced:

  > Make a copy of ffmpeg under a new name -- avconv.
  >
  > It will be further developed with a few incompatible changes.
  >
  > ffmpeg.c will stay as is for some time, so any scripts using it won't be
  >   broken.
- **27 Jul 2011** - commit [791a86c37a03b94207bc2d0ad4cbe7f39d7e495a](http://git.libav.org/?p=libav.git;a=commit;h=791a86c37a03b94207bc2d0ad4cbe7f39d7e495a)

  A warning is added to the forked version of `ffmpeg.c` source code, that may be misleading to users who haven't noticed about the fork and that they are not using FFmpeg anymore.
- **12 Jan 2012** - commit [0fec2cb15cc6ff1fcc724c774ec36abadcb7b6ad](http://git.libav.org/?p=libav.git;a=commit;h=0fec2cb15cc6ff1fcc724c774ec36abadcb7b6ad)

  `ffmpeg.c` is removed from the source code.

### Official announcements on libav.org

The following posts are from the news section (with the oldest in last):

> ## August 09 2011
>
> **Updated on 12.09.2011.**
>
> For consistency with our new name we have renamed **ffplay** to **avplay**,
>   **ffserver** to **avserver** and **ffprobe** to **avprobe**. Their behavior is the
>   same, just the names were changed.
>
> With **ffmpeg** (the command line tool) we decided to use this opportunity
>   to fix some longstanding usability problems, which involves breaking
>   compatibility. Therefore we have added a new tool named **avconv** which
>   is based on **ffmpeg**, but has a different (hopefully more powerful and
>   easier to use) syntax for some options. **ffmpeg** will be kept in its
>   current state for some time, so no scripts or frontends using it will
>   break. However it will not be developed further.
>
> Differences between **avconv** and **ffmpeg** are:
>
> [...]
>
> Note that the **avconv** interface is not considered stable yet. More
>   incompatible changes may come in the following weeks. We will announce
>   here when **avconv** is stable.

And earlier in 2011:

> ## Mar 18, 2011
>
> We have just pushed another point release from our 0.6 release branch:
>   [Libav 0.6.2](https://libav.org/download.html#release_0.6). This is another maintenance-only release addressing two
>   security issues.
>
> From now on, we will be using our new project name **libav**. But don't
>   worry, compared to the preceding release 0.6.1, the only functional
>   changes are the two security fixes for the VC1 and APE decoders. This
>   means that libav provides a painless drop-in replacement for existing
>   FFmpeg installations.
>
> Moreover, we are proud to accompany this source release with
>   executables and libraries for the [win32 platform](http://win32.libav.org/). These binaries
>   include H.264 encoding using the bundled x264 library. Enjoy!
>
> Distributors and system integrators are encouraged to update and share
>   their patches against our release branches.
>
> ## Mar 17, 2011
>
> We have just pushed another point release from our 0.5 release branch:
>   [FFmpeg 0.5.4](https://libav.org/download.html#release_0.5). This is another maintenance-only release that addresses
>   a number of security issues.
>
> Distributors and system integrators are encouraged to update and share
>   their patches against our release branches.
>
> ## March 13, 2011
>
> We, as a group of FFmpeg developers, have decided to continue
>   developing FFmpeg under the name Libav. All existing infrastructure
>   will be transferred to the libav.org domain.
>
> - Website: http://www.libav.org/
> - Git: git://git.libav.org/libav.git (see http://libav.org/download.html)
> - FATE: http://fate.libav.org/
> - Roundup: https://roundup.libav.org/
> - Patchwork: http://patches.libav.org/
> - Mailinglists: http://lists.libav.org/ (developer list: libav-devel@libav.org)
>
> You can update your git repository using the following command:
>
> ```
> git remote set-url origin 'git://git.libav.org/libav'
> ```
>
> For now we are still reachable over FFmpeg's mailing lists and IRC
>   channels but we will migrate to libav.org counterparts. For a
>   transition period both the website and source might still contain
>   references to FFmpeg. These will disappear over time, except where
>   historically relevant.
>
> ## February 24, 2011
>
> FFmpeg development has moved to Git, and the SVN repository is no
>   longer updated. The SVN repository may be removed in a near future, so
>   you're recommended to use a [Git repository](https://libav.org/download.html) instead.
>
> The last revision committed to SVN was r26402 on 2011-01-19 and
>   replaced the svn:external libswscale with a standalone copy.

Note that FFmpeg development has in fact moved to a Git repository by now and that there are two Git repositories. See the corresponding projects download page.

Comment: When did this change happen?

Comment: @Seth Do you mean shipping of libav instead of FFmpeg or dropping of the transitional package? I found a mail that points to a Team Report from the Technical Board and and also added a link to the source package on launchpad where one can compare the saucy and trusty package listings, but I don't know the details.

Comment: I was referring to dropping the package, although I'm interested in the time-frames for both if possible.

Comment: I might move the how to install ffmpeg from ppa to the end.  As a "If you're really in to swimming against the tide, and you already read all these things... then you can do this."  Instead of putting it all the way at the front.  Like, encourage using things that are in main/uni/multi if you can avoid PPAs.

Comment: @Seth I just added what I could find by digging through libav's git tree and what they published as news on the project page. Some mails from the FFmpeg mailing list seem to have been removed (e.g. http://lists.mplayerhq.hu/pipermail/ffmpeg-devel/2011-January/103440.html). This answer may now be a bit to lengthy, but give some directions for the ones that are curious.

Comment: @hbdgaf I added http://askubuntu.com/q/35629/ as a heads up. The FFmpeg PPA was already last, not considering the newly added history section. Instead of pure politics (and probably hatred), I'd like to discuss different functionality like the new deinterlace filter `w3fdif` in FFmpeg (but that's off-topic for this question). I don't understand why I'm obviously getting downvoted (I'm not blaming you in particular.), for trying to objectively explain what happened. I don't have any affiliation with one of these projects and intend to be as objective as possible.

Comment: Returns in 15.04, but absent in 16.04 (?!?)

Comment: What do you mean? The package exists in the repositories and contains binaries http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/ffmpeg/filelist

Answer (score 118):

`ffmpeg` was replaced in previous releases by the `avconv` program from the libav project.

To install `avconv` you need to install the `libav-tools` package:

```
sudo apt-get install libav-tools
```

`avconv` is very similar to `ffmpeg`, but they also have some differences in syntax.

**Edit:** It seems Ubuntu 16.04LTS has again `ffmpeg` in their repositories, so libav-tools is a dummy package and only creates an alias `avconv -> ffmpeg` (and others)

Comment: Easy answer but all the directions online say how to use ffmpeg to do stuff, not avconv, and that's what brought me to this page. With apologies to Rutrus: minus one. - Maybe if you explained the differences, we'd be able to work with it.

Comment: @aaron-hall I think your -1 is unfair. You expect something wrong. The question made in 2014 is very clear: Is it missing in 14.04? And the answer is yes, in some previous versions ffmpeg as much was only an alias for avconv. It doesn't matter what you were looking for. Maybe you don't read the title of the page before click this page. But don't worry, I will edit with a disclaimer for people with reputation 184 who doesn't know how to stackexchange works.

Comment: I still have 14.04, and I want to use ffmpeg - is avconv a drop-in replacement or what? ***What are the differences?***

Comment: The vast majority of **your** rep on this site is due to this answer, which I could have written based **solely** on the material in the top answer. You shoud *earn* your rep by writing a decent answer that says, at least in short and in general what the differences are. Hand-waving is a waste of time. Unless it truly is just an alias, in which case there shouldn't be any differences in syntax. And if you do, you'll reverse my opinion of the answer, but as it currently stands, it contradicts itself! Let me know when I can delete these comments.

Comment: libav-tools is a fork from ffmpeg. `ffmpeg` was replaced by `avconv` from 2012 to 2014 in Ubuntu repos. You can ask this new question for your answer, or [find one yourself](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12443023/what-are-the-differences-between-ffmpeg-and-libav). You can use ffmpeg again since Ubuntu 15.04. Abstract: libav is compatible with ffmpeg syntax, but not in the reverse.

Comment: @Rutrus If I'm not mistaken you've written that backwards. ffmpeg supports libav syntax (though there may be some incompatibilities), but the reverse is not true.

Comment: This still work in 2017 and is perfect.

Answer (score 49):

ffmpeg had removed repo of Ubuntu, instead of libav. you should add ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/trusty-media
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg
```

watch your output

Comment: It has to be: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/trusty-media :) can't edit this, not enough characters changed.

Comment: That is not the PPA listed on FFmpeg.org as the current official PPA. (Also the project member maintaining the PPA may change, that's the reason why I decided to not includ instructions on how to add a certain PPA.) Also if you look at this PPA it updates a whole lot more packages than just ffmpeg.

Comment: This doesn't work anymore.

Comment: It does work. I just added this PPA and am now installing FFMPEG.

Comment: It doesn't work for Utopic Unicorn though :(

Comment: Great! It works for me with Linux Mint 17.2.

Comment: @LiveWireBT (and others) that PPA is now provided as the Ubuntu link on the [FFmpeg downloads page](https://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html)...

Answer (score 44):

You can also use this PPA:
[ppa:jon-severinsson/ffmpeg](https://launchpad.net/~jon-severinsson/+archive/ffmpeg)

**Edit:** This ppa has been deleted from Launchpad, I don't know why.
Instead of it, you can use the [samrog131](https://launchpad.net/~samrog131/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) PPA (for Trusty, Utopic & Vivid)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:samrog131/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg-set-alternatives
```

The PPA also contains other packages that you may not want. Remove the ppa after installation.

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:samrog131/ppa
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: Fixed apt-add-repository -> add-apt-repository. If apt-add-repository doesnt work for you anymore, try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13018626/add-apt-repository-not-found

Comment: That's basically the same information I posted in my answer, but without the warning that should always be given before advising users to install packages from PPAs. Also there is the possibility that someone else will take over maintenance of an ffmpeg PPA in the future or that the PPA will just be moved or renamed. Therefore linking to official instructions is the right way, as it reduces redundancy and maintenance effort.

Comment: This one doesn't provide GStreamer-ffmpeg integration. @Duong's answer (`mc3man`'s PPA) does.

Comment: This ppa does not support utopic.

Comment: Installing this on my ubuntu 14.04 LTS allowed me to display mp4 videos on ipython notebooks.

Comment: +1. From `https://launchpad.net/~jon-severinsson/+archive/ubuntu/ffmpeg`: "Please note that this is *actual* FFmpeg, from ffmpeg.org. Recent Debian and Ubuntu packages feature Libav (from libav.org), a prominent FFmpeg fork"

Comment: And now this PPA was deleted.

Answer (score 8):

FFMPEG package was removed since some time now from Debian repositories. There's still an [ongoing debate](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=729203) about including the package again in the repositories. Ubuntu as Debian derivative, depends of the decitions made upstream. Since long ago, the package was just empty with an dependency to libav. This was changed in 12 May 2012 when the package was dropped and removed from the archives:

```
libav (6:0.8.99-1537-gacb2c79-1) experimental; urgency=low

  * New upstream snapshot
    - Drop patches applied upstream
    - Longer build libpostproc, dropped upstream
    - follow soname bump of libavcodec and libavformat 53->54
    - New library: libswresample
  * no longer build and use dirac, removed upstream in favor of libschroedinger
  * remove deprecated ffmpeg package
  * bump shlibs version

 -- Reinhard Tartler <siretart@tauware.de>  Sat, 12 May 2012 22:02:03 +0200
```

Comment: Don't say it was empty, the packages in saucy contain a binary `dpkg --contents ffmpeg_0.8.7-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb [...] -rwxr-xr-x root/root    106624 2013-10-11 10:41 ./usr/bin/ffmpeg`.

Comment: @LiveWireBT could you use the package alone? That single file was just a binary to link avconv binary. Transitional packages are always deemed as empty packages.

Comment: We may just be thinking the same thing and are misunderstanding each other. :)

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error when trying to run

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```

So I combined a few other answers, as well as the content from [this site](https://launchpad.net/~mc3man/+archive/ubuntu/trusty-media), to obtain the following recipe that worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:mc3man/trusty-media  # ignore warning if not found
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/trusty-media
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```

Now I can see that ffmpeg has been installed:

```
sudo find / -type f -name "ffmpeg"
```

returns `/opt/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg`

From the bash prompt, the command `ffmpeg` should now work from any folder.

Comment: `dist-upgrade` is not required for installing `ffmpeg`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to install ffmpeg 2.2.1 (from source) in Ubuntu 14.04, you can give it a try using the following options:

For 64-bit OS:

List of Dependencies:

```
yasm frei0r-plugins-dev gnutls-bin libgnutls-dev libass-dev libgsm1-dev libmp3lame-dev libopencv-dev libopenjpeg-dev libopus-dev libpulse-dev libschroedinger-dev libsoxr-dev libspeex-dev libtheora-dev libv4l-dev libvorbis-dev libvpx-dev libx264-dev libxvidcore-dev libopenal-dev libcdio-paranoia-dev
```

Compilation options:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/bin --datadir=/usr/share/ffmpeg --incdir=/usr/include/ffmpeg --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/  --mandir=/usr/share/man --arch=x86_64 --optflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic' --enable-bzlib --disable-crystalhd --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-libass --enable-libcdio --enable-libdc1394 --disable-indev=jack --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-openal --enable-libopencv --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-x11grab --enable-avfilter --enable-avresample --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --disable-debug --disable-stripping --shlibdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ --enable-runtime-cpudetect
```

For a 32 bit OS:

List of Dependencies:

```
yasm frei0r-plugins-dev gnutls-bin libgnutls-dev libass-dev libgsm1-dev libmp3lame-dev libopencv-dev libopenjpeg-dev libopus-dev libpulse-dev libschroedinger-dev libsoxr-dev libspeex-dev libtheora-dev libv4l-dev libvorbis-dev libvpx-dev libx264-dev libxvidcore-dev libopenal-dev libcdio-paranoia-dev libopencore-amrwb-dev libopencore-amrnb-dev
```

Compilation options:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib --shlibdir=/usr/lib --mandir=/usr/share/man --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-postproc --enable-avfilter --enable-pthreads --enable-x11grab --enable-vdpau --disable-avisynth --enable-frei0r --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --extra-cflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m32 -march=i686 -mtune=atom -fasynchronous-unwind-tables' --disable-stripping
```

For more information see my [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MRrGNIuLJ40).

Comment: Why suggest building as shared for amd64??, there is little to be gained & may break other apps that depend on those shared libs.

Comment: You forgot to mention where to download the sources

Answer (score 0):

If you want the latest release fresh off github which satisfies the likes of errors generated from youtube-dl

```
ERROR: ffprobe or avprobe not found. Please install one.
```

then issue these cmds :

```
sudo apt-get build-dep ffmpeg

git clone https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg.git

cd FFmpeg

./configure   --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-openal --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzmq --enable-libssh --enable-libsoxr --enable-libx264 --enable-libopencv --enable-libx265

make -j8
sudo make install
```

enjoy,

Answer (score -1):

First install `avconv`:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libav-tools
```

Then create a soft link to `avconv` named `ffmpeg`:

```
$ sudo ln -s /usr/bin/avconv /usr/bin/ffmpeg
```

Now you can use `ffmpeg` normally.

Comment: Polluting `/usr/bin` with symlinks is generally not a good idea. What will happen if you upgrade to a moden Ubuntu version and try to install  `ffmpeg` from the repo? Also, `avconv` is a poor substitute for `ffmpeg`: it is missing many features, filters, etc.

Answer (score -1):

I was spent 2 weeks to install newest version ffmpeg 2.8.11. This version is used for Ubuntu 16.04. I advise you should install this version. I tested on Ubuntu 12.04 and Ubuntu 14.04 and it worked well. You can install libav-tools like directions above but you will have a problem about compatibility. Because libav-tools and ffmpeg now was developed by two different group.
Following my directions. If you have any problem can sent me via an email: hohaidang.khtn@gmail.com

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get -y install build-essential checkinstall git libfaac-dev libgpac-dev libmp3lame-dev libopencore-amrnb-dev libopencore-amrwb-dev librtmp-dev libtheora-dev libvorbis-dev pkg-config texi2html yasm zlib1g-dev  libavcodec-extra-53
$ sudo apt-get -y install autoconf automake build-essential libass-dev libfreetype6-dev libtool libva-dev libvdpau-dev libvorbis-dev libxcb1-dev libxcb-shm0-dev libxcb-xfixes0-dev pkg-config texinfo zlib1g-dev
$ sudo apt-get install libdc1394-22 libdc1394-22-dev libgsm1 libgsm1-dev libopenjpeg-dev libschroedinger-1.0-0 libschroedinger-dev libschroedinger-doc libspeex-dev libfaac-dev libmp3lame-dev libopencore-amrnb-dev libopencore-amrwb-dev libsdl1.2-dev libtheora-dev libvorbis-dev libx11-dev libxfixes-dev libxvidcore-dev libx264-dev
$ wget https://www.ffmpeg.org/releases/ffmpeg-2.8.11.tar.xz
$ tar xf ffmpeg-2.8.11.tar.xz
$ cd ffmpeg-2.8.11/
./configure --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-nonfree --enable-postproc --enable-x11grab --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libfaac --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --disable-yasm // disable yasm if you are using Ubuntu 12.04, if not --enable-yasm
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

Check ffmpeg, ffserver, ffplay, ffprobe in terminal.
Good luck