# Converting .rm to .flv using terminal?

Tags: rm, video-conversion

Is there anyway to convert .rm to .flv using terminal? Because .rm file is not running in Mplayer in my Ubuntu 12.04.

> **OS Detail:**
>   Linux HP-CQ40 3.8.0-39-generic #58~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 2 21:33:17 UTC 2014
>   i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

Comment: MPlayer should be able to play all Real Media files so this is a little odd. Could you run the file from the commandline with MPlayer and post the full terminal output here?

Answer (score 4):

Easiest is with avconv (and no special options):

```
avconv -i samplevideo.rm samplevideo.flv
```

(in case someone suggests ffmpeg: [Is FFmpeg missing from the official repositories in 14.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/432542/is-ffmpeg-missing-from-the-official-repositories-in-14-04) )

Installation of avconv:

```
sudo apt-get install libav-tools
```

---

For all your GUI users (yeah you!):

[image]

Comment: But Op mentioned he has 12.04 is it missing ?

Comment: Its not working.`prashant@HP-CQ40:~/study/Discrete_by_Shai$ avconv -i 02_lect_01.rm 02_lect_01.flv
avconv version 0.8.10-4:0.8.10-0ubuntu0.12.04.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the Libav developers
  built on Feb  6 2014 20:59:08 with gcc 4.6.3
[NULL @ 0x9d35ba0] Unsupported video codec
[NULL @ 0x9d37960] Unsupported video codec
Input #0, rm, from '02_lect_01.rm':
  Metadata:
    title           : Untitled
    . 
     
  Duration: 01:19:01.32, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 301 kb/s
    Stream #0.0: Data: [0][0][0][0] / 0x0000, 32 kb/s
    Stream #0.1: Data: [0][0][0][0] / 0x0000, 265 kb/s
`

Comment: @RinzWind Thanks for replying at speed of ***light***(3 * 10^8 m/s).

Answer (score 0):

You can use **ffmpeg** :

```
ffmpeg -i file.rm file.flv
```

Comment: I tried ffmpeg also.Its result is same as avconv .No conversion.