# Installing xvst on ubuntu 14.04? ffmpeg missing

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, ffmpeg

I'm trying to install xvst: http://xviservicethief.sourceforge.net

on my ubuntu 14.04 64bits

I have tried adding the repositories as described over here: http://linuxaria.com/article/download-your-favorite-video-with-xvideoservicethief

or using the deb from the getdeb link on main site (download page).

however both methods complain that ffmpeg is missing. And when looking for ffmpeg it seems like it has been replaced by another package and that the previous ffmpeg is actually something else anyway so better compile it. I'm confused to as what would be the best way to go for installing xvst.

so, for an newbie, how would should I go about installing xvst, and I really hope I don't have to compile any packages myself (unless the step by step would be idiot proof)

Most grateful for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install ffmpeg from a personal archive with:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:jon-severinsson/ffmpeg
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```

Take note of this topic regarding the end of ffmpeg: [Is FFmpeg missing from the official repositories in 14.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/432542/is-ffmpeg-missing-from-the-official-repositories-in-14-04)

Comment: Worked like a charm, I'm glad it was so easy :-) Thank you!