# How to install ffmpeg on Ubuntu 14.04 (32-bit)?

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, ffmpeg

When I try:

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```

I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package ffmpeg is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'ffmpeg' has no installation candidate
```

And I don't know how to install ppa packages.

Comment: this means there is nothing like ffmpeg in ubuntu repository you have to download it and install it manually from terminal

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/432542/is-ffmpeg-missing-from-the-official-repositories-in-14-04 (`aconv` is the new `ffmpeg` ;) )

Comment: @Rinzwind - I answered what he asked :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try these running these commands on your system to install ffmpeg

```
cd ~/ffmpeg_sources
wget http://ffmpeg.org/releases/ffmpeg-snapshot.tar.bz2
tar xjvf ffmpeg-snapshot.tar.bz2
cd ffmpeg
PATH="$PATH:$HOME/bin" PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib/pkgconfig" ./configure \
  --prefix="$HOME/ffmpeg_build" \
  --extra-cflags="-I$HOME/ffmpeg_build/include" \
  --extra-ldflags="-L$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib" \
  --bindir="$HOME/bin" \
  --extra-libs="-ldl" \
  --enable-gpl \
  --enable-libass \
  --enable-libfdk-aac \
  --enable-libfreetype \
  --enable-libmp3lame \
  --enable-libopus \
  --enable-libtheora \
  --enable-libvorbis \
  --enable-libvpx \
  --enable-libx264 \
  --enable-nonfree \
  --enable-x11grab
PATH="$PATH:$HOME/bin" make
make install
make distclean
hash -r
```

for more details see [this](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu) installation guide

Comment: Your answer is correct. I am now using ffmpeg.

Comment: I am unable to install ffmpeg until i removed this 
  --enable-x11grab