# How to convert flv to mp3 on ubuntu 14 without ffmpeg

Tags: 14.04, ffmpeg, mp3, convert, flv

And how to do any convertions in Ubuntu 14 if there is no ffmpeg anymore? When I last use it prev version I had warning to use different tool but I don't remember what it was.

Comment: Found info here http://askubuntu.com/questions/432542/is-ffmpeg-missing-from-the-official-repositories-in-14-04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Ubuntu >=14.04 just use `avconv` instead of `ffmpeg` it's a fork and it's seems it accept same command line options.

Install the `libav-tools` package to get it.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Sound Converter.

> Sound Converter is a gnome sound conversion available for Linux. You
>   can convert music files into another format (OOG, MP3 and Flac). The
>   tool is very simple, just add the files, set the destination directory
>   and convert the files.<sup>[SC](http://soundconverter.org/)</sup>

To install, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install soundconverter
```

Answer (score 1):

Straight forward: `avconv -i /path/video.flv /path/audio.mp3`

Answer (score 0):

You can still use `ffmpeg` from FFmpeg if you prefer (like I do). You have two main choices, and a PPA:

## Download a static build of `ffmpeg`

This is easy and supports MP3 encoding. Just go to the [FFmpeg Download](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html#build-linux) page and get one of the "Linux Static Builds". Or if you're lazy:

```
wget http://ffmpeg.gusari.org/static/32bit/ffmpeg.static.32bit.latest.tar.gz
tar xzvf ffmpeg.static.32bit.latest.tar.gz
```

Then execute the binary: `./ffmpeg -i input ...`

## Compile `ffmpeg`

Another option is to compile. It takes more time, but allows you to fully customize your build. See [Compile FFmpeg on Ubuntu, Debian, or Mint](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu).

## mc3man's PPA

See [Ubuntu Multimedia for Trusty](https://launchpad.net/~mc3man/+archive/ubuntu/trusty-media).

---

### Example command for MP3 encoding

```
ffmpeg -i input -codec:a libmp3lame -q:a 4 output.mp3
```

### Example command for stream copy

If your flv input already contains MP3 audio (`ffmpeg` will tell you), then you can simply re-mux instead of re-encode:

```
ffmpeg -i input -codec:a copy -map 0:a output.mp3
```

#### Also see

- [Who can tell me the difference and relation between ffmpeg, libav, and avconv?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9477115/1109017)
- [FFmpeg Wiki: MP3 Encoding Guide](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/MP3)