# How to draw a picture with text in the center of that via command-line?

Tags: command-line, graphics, imagemagick, inkscape

I need to paint an image with text in the center via command-line to further put into the video. A simple yellow text on black background.

I tried `FFmpeg` way:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -r 1 -i b.png -b:v 1M -vf "scale=320:240, drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/DejaVuSans.ttf: text='Test Text'" -vcodec mpeg4 -acodec aac preroll.mp4
```

Which gave me the following error:

```
[AVFilterGraph @ 0xf56020] No such filter: 'drawtext'
```

I tried to install *ivtools* and tried `drawtool` and `idraw` which are obviously for desktop environments.

How to create a simple image with text in Ubuntu programatically?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

What about this command:

```
convert -background black -size 800x480 -fill "#ff0080"  -pointsize 72 -gravity center label:'Ask Ubuntu' output.png
```

[image]

By using above command you create an empty .png image which its background color is black.

[-background *color*](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#background)

   set the background color. 

   the default background color (if none is specified or found in the image) is white.

The created image size will be 800x480(`width[xheight]`).

[-size *width[xheight][+offset]*](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#size)

   set the width and height of the raw image.

[-fill *color*](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#fill)

   color to use when filling a graphic primitive.

This option accepts a color name, a hex color, or a numerical RGB, RGBA, HSL, HSLA, CMYK, or CMYKA specification. See [Color Names](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/color.php) for a description of how to properly specify the color argument.

For example,

```
 -fill blue
 -fill "#ff0080"
 -fill "rgb(255,0,128)"
```

Enclose the color specification in quotation marks to prevent the "#" or the parentheses from being interpreted by your shell.

To print a complete list of color names, use the [-list *color*](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#list) option.

[-pointsize *size*](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#pointsize)

   pointsize of the PostScript, OPTION1, or TrueType font.

[-gravity *type*](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#gravity)

   sets the current gravity suggestion for various other settings and options.

Choices include: NorthWest, North, NorthEast, West, Center, East, SouthWest, South, SouthEast. Use [-list *gravity*](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#list) to get a complete list of [-gravity](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#gravity) settings available in your ImageMagick installation.

`label:'your Text Here'` write your text into image.png.

Also [see more examples](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/#label).

<sub>[See full command-line options](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#draw)</sub>

Answer (score 8):

If we were talking about outside video, I would make a simple SVG in inkscape with a placeholder string like `OLISTRING`, get it how I want it to look then manipulate that on the command line to substitute my dynamic text in. And use Inkscape to rasterise it.

```
inkscape -z -e intro.png -w 1920 -h 1080 <(sed 's/OLISTRING/My Video!/' drawing.svg)
```

The real benefit with this approach is you're only limited by what you can do in Inkscape... You also get a pretty crisp output thanks to Inkscape's rendering engine.

Here's the outcome:

[image]

As rendered from this (going through my `sed`)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->

<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   width="1920"
   height="1080"
   id="svg2"
   version="1.1"
   inkscape:version="0.48.4 r9939"
   sodipodi:docname="New document 1">
  <defs
     id="defs4" />
  <sodipodi:namedview
     id="base"
     pagecolor="#000000"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1.0"
     inkscape:pageopacity="1"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:zoom="0.35"
     inkscape:cx="375"
     inkscape:cy="520"
     inkscape:document-units="px"
     inkscape:current-layer="layer1"
     showgrid="false"
     inkscape:window-width="1920"
     inkscape:window-height="1130"
     inkscape:window-x="-2"
     inkscape:window-y="-3"
     inkscape:window-maximized="1" />
  <metadata
     id="metadata7">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title></dc:title>
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <g
     inkscape:label="Layer 1"
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     id="layer1"
     transform="translate(0,27.637817)">
    <flowRoot
       xml:space="preserve"
       id="flowRoot2985"
       style="fill:black;stroke:none;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-width:1px;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-linecap:butt;fill-opacity:1;font-family:Sans;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;font-size:72px;line-height:125%;letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;text-anchor:middle;text-align:center"><flowRegion
         id="flowRegion2987"><rect
           id="rect2989"
           width="1917.1428"
           height="662.85712"
           x="0"
           y="174.28572"
           style="text-anchor:middle;text-align:center;font-size:72px" /></flowRegion><flowPara
         id="flowPara2991"></flowPara></flowRoot>    <flowRoot
       xml:space="preserve"
       id="flowRoot2993"
       style="font-size:40px;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;line-height:125%;letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;font-family:Sans"
       transform="translate(0,192.36218)"><flowRegion
         id="flowRegion2995"><rect
           id="rect2997"
           width="1917.1428"
           height="700"
           x="0"
           y="151.42857" /></flowRegion><flowPara
         id="flowPara2999"
         style="font-size:244px;font-weight:bold;text-align:center;text-anchor:middle;fill:#ffff00;-inkscape-font-specification:Sans Bold">OLISTRING</flowPara></flowRoot>    <flowRoot
       xml:space="preserve"
       id="flowRoot3001"
       style="fill:black;stroke:none;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-width:1px;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-linecap:butt;fill-opacity:1;font-family:Sans;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;font-size:40px;line-height:125%;letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px"><flowRegion
         id="flowRegion3003"><rect
           id="rect3005"
           width="0"
           height="85.714287"
           x="962.85712"
           y="397.14285" /></flowRegion><flowPara
         id="flowPara3007"></flowPara></flowRoot>  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 7):

I found a solution:
installed Imagestick:

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

And then I used something like:

```
convert -pointsize 36 -fill red -draw 'text 10,10 "Loh pidr text" ' b.png test1.jpg
```

And then use

```
man convert
```

to see documentation and play aroud.

Answer (score -1):

The ffmpeg command didn't work because [ubuntu doesn't have ffmpeg, it has libav instead](https://askubuntu.com/a/432585/87531).

Try `ffmpeg -version` to confirm (will return 0.8.something IIRC).

If you get the latest version (2.4.3) from http://ffmpeg.org then drawtext will work.

Comment: Bizarre! I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 and `ffmpeg` returns version 1.2.6. I know that there was some disagreement between `ffmpeg` and `avconv`. I notice that `avconv` is a link to `ffmpeg`. So weird.