# How can I install ffmpeg on Lubuntu 14.04?

Tags: lubuntu, ffmpeg

It seems that the original `ffmpeg` has been dropped by Debian for the moment (in favour of the fork `libav`)  but will be back in 15.

Some people seem to think `ffmpeg` is deprecated or stale: it's not, it's just that in 2011,  a group of devs decided to fork it as avcodec (`libav`).

I use `get_iplayer` for BBC downloads and that requires `ffmpeg` for its automated format conversions. So I was a bit surprised to find that a brand new install of Lubuntu 14.04 (LTS)  doesn't include ffmpeg.

How can I install `ffmpeg`?

Comment: It's lovely you want to share this. Please [edit] to make it a Q&A pair, not just a Q. This isn't a blogging site or a forum. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/ Check out the [help] to learn more.

Comment: Meh. Already posted: http://askubuntu.com/a/451158/158442

Comment: Sorry muru  -  I may be being dim, but when I as user add information like this, I'm not sure how I'm expected to know of or find someone else's contribution (as you've flagged here).  Surely this is a repository of advice isnt' it ?   so just denigrating someone's input because 'something similar exists' is not the point.    I've looked at the ref (158442) you flagged, and it doesn't replace my comment.  I'm sure some users would be pleased to have my comment, also.  It's not as if there's a shortage of disc space..

Comment: Tim - re yours - thanks - I will need to go read up on that - not sure how to create a Q+A but I'm sure it's explained in your link.   Just trying to assist people here (as they assist me).

Answer (score 1):

Answer posted as Question:

> There are lots of bits of advice on the web most of which doesn't work because of stale repositories and so on. Eventually,  I found the advice below [from elsewhere on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29125229/how-to-reinstall-ffmpeg-clean-on-ubuntu-14-04).
>
> I used this on Lubuntu 14.04
>
> ```
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/trusty-media
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
> sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
> ```
>
> I opted not to do the distro-upgrade step,  but it still worked overall for me.