# How to compile ffmpeg with https support

Tags: ffmpeg, openssl

I have installed both openssl and openssl-dev, with these:

```
sudo apt-get install openssl
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

And has install ffmpeg by these:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/trusty-media
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```

Now I would like to enable https protocol for `ffmpeg`. I did try these:

```
user@user-VirtualBox:~/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg$ ./configure --enable-openssl
```

And its listed in the `Enabled protocols` list.

After that ran these commands:

```
make
make install
```

But with no help. And if check the `ffmpeg -protocols`, the `https` protocols is not listed there.

I am using ubuntu inside a virtualbox, and I not very good at it. If you could please guide me through how to compile `openssl` with ffmpeg to enable https protocol I would be very thank grateful. Thank you.

Comment: Try `/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg` - also what is the output of `whereis ffmpeg`? Also, what version of ubuntu are you using?

Comment: You weren't actually using that ppa's ffmpeg as https was & continues to be enabled..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR**

```
./configure --enable-gnutls
```

---

Open a terminal and follow the commands below:

For Trusty you need a PPA, recommended on the [ffmpeg download page](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html#build-linux)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/trusty-media
sudo apt-get update
```

After that

```
cd
apt-get source ffmpeg
sudo apt-get build-dep ffmpeg
```

Replace `2.5.7` with your version:

```
cd ffmpeg-2.5.7
./configure --enable-gnutls
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -uc -b
```

After that, install the package in the parent folder (`cd ..`).

Comment: There's not apt-get source ffmpeg

Comment: @Robin what do you mean? ffmpeg is in the standard repositories.

Comment: Yes. I have no idea why. It should have been. But its not there.

Comment: @Robin sorry, not for Trusty http://askubuntu.com/a/432585/367165

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you prefer gnutls over openssl?

Comment: @ElliottB Maybe this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/523188/ffmpeg-claims-openssl-is-not-compatible-with-gpl-v3

Answer (score 5):

Add --enable-openssl,
This is what I use. Make sure the library is inatalled, debian: sudo apt install libssl-dev, or redhat: yum install -y openssl-devel

```
PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH" PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib/pkgconfig" ./configure \
  --prefix="$HOME/ffmpeg_build" \
  --pkg-config-flags="--static" \
  --extra-cflags="-I$HOME/ffmpeg_build/include" \
  --extra-ldflags="-L$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib" \
  --bindir="$HOME/bin" \
  --enable-gpl \
  --enable-libass \
  --enable-libfdk-aac \
  --enable-libfreetype \
  --enable-libmp3lame \
  --enable-libopus \
  --enable-libtheora \
  --enable-libvorbis \
  --enable-libvpx \
  --enable-libx264 \
  --enable-libx265 \
  --enable-openssl \
  --enable-nonfree
PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH" make
make install
hash -r
```