# How do I install ffmpeg and codecs?

Tags: multimedia, codecs

i am trying to install a video script and I need to install FFmpeg with all the codecs. I have tried many tutorials online and I didn't succeed.
FFmpeg (from SVN)

- x264 Library for mencoder

Comment: Tell us **what** you tried and **how** it failed.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

To install it :

If you're using **Ubuntu 14.04** :

`ffmpeg` was replaced in previous releases by the `avconv` program from the libav project.

To install `avconv` you need to install the `libav-tools` package:

```
sudo apt-get install libav-tools
```

Or use PPA :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/trusty-media
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg
```

If you're using **Ubuntu 15.04** :

FFmpeg Returns To The Official Ubuntu Repositories With Ubuntu 15.04 Vivid Vervet.

Just type :

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```

For more info :

[Is FFmpeg missing from the official repositories in 14.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/432542/is-ffmpeg-missing-from-the-official-repositories-in-14-04)

[Install FFmpeg on Ubuntu 14.10 Using PPA](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/install-ffmpeg-on-ubuntu-14-10-using-ppa.html)

Comment: If i install it from the given ppa, will it be installed with all the codecs?

Comment: @Arjon11, i'm not sure ! but if it doesn't work, you can take a look at [MPlayer](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/design7/news.html), or at [How to install the transcoding tools on Ubuntu 14.04](https://www.vimp.com/en/web/faq-installation/items/how-to-install-the-transcoding-tools-on-ubuntu-1404.html)

Comment: And this seems to no longer work in 16.04

Comment: FYI: libav-tools alone does not work on ubuntu 14.04 but the ppa does work.