# install FFmpeg codecs to make gifcurry work

Tags: software-installation, ffmpeg, codecs, gif

I'm trying to use [gifcurry](https://github.com/lettier/gifcurry#how-do-i-get-a-copy-of-gifcurry) on Ubuntu 16.04 but I get the following warning which will not allow me to select my mp4 I created in KdenLive.

[image]

I installed [gifcurry](https://github.com/lettier/gifcurry#how-do-i-get-a-copy-of-gifcurry) as instructed on the site. It opens up fine.

I also [tried installing libav-tools](https://askubuntu.com/questions/691109/how-do-i-install-ffmpeg-and-codecs) but I still get this yellow error or warning which will not allow me to open my MP4.

Does anyone know how to install the proper decoders so I can open my mp4 file? Is there anyway to simply install a whole lot of them which will probably cover it for my mp4?

Comment: This may be better answered by gifcurry's support or community since as far as I can tell it's not software included with Ubuntu

Comment: Probably, but if anyone know how to install more decoders into ffmpeg, that would help a lot.

Comment: Even their snap has the same error about ffmpeg, it shouldn't as it's provided in the snap. What you can try is from the gifcurry page you linked, https://github.com/lettier/gifcurry#i-use-linux click on the 'prebuilt version' link. After downloading extract. Inside the extracted folder there will be a bin folder. Drop the gifcurry_gui file into a terminal, press enter. Make sure the main gstreamer1.0 plugins are installed (gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad, gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly, gstreamer1.0-libav & also gstreamer1.0-gtk3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm running ubuntu 18.10, same error using the snap

`sudo snap remove gifcurry`

download gifcurry AppImage and the 'handy' AppImage install script
https://github.com/lettier/gifcurry#i-use-linux-penguin

`chmod +x ./gifcurry-app-image-install.sh`

launch `./gifcurry-app-image-install.sh`

on launch i had one error, fixed by the gstreamer plugin install listed here:
https://github.com/lettier/gifcurry/issues/23

Answer (score 1):

According to gifcurry's website, gifcurry requires FFMPEG 3.0 or above.  Ubuntu 16.04 only has FFMPEG 2.8.

This may or may not be your issue, but you may want to ask for help from gifcurry's support for further clarification.

Comment: +1. I did try uninstalling FFMPEG 2.8 and installed 3.x. But I still get the issue. Thanks for the suggestion. Perhaps I should stop being lazy and upgrade Ubuntu to 18.04.